# Perform linear regression on rows of data based on ID in R

Tags: r, group-by, linear-regression

I want to apply a linear regression to rows in my data frame based on an ID number. I want to do this using the ch4_ppm column. For example, for all the rows that have 'measurement_id'==1, do a regression on this set and store the results in a data frame. I have a total of 157 sets I want to repeat this for. Below is a sample from my dataset.

```
structure(list(time = c("2022-07-26 09:11:40", "2022-07-26 09:11:45",  "2022-07-26 09:11:50", "2022-07-26 09:11:55", "2022-07-26 09:12:00",  "2022-07-26 09:12:05", "2022-07-26 09:12:10", "2022-07-26 09:12:15",  "2022-07-26 09:12:20", "2022-07-26 09:12:25", "2022-07-26 09:12:30",  "2022-07-26 09:12:35", "2022-07-26 09:12:40", "2022-07-26 09:12:45",  "2022-07-26 09:12:50", "2022-07-26 09:12:55", "2022-07-26 09:13:00",  "2022-07-26 09:13:05", "2022-07-26 09:13:10", "2022-07-26 09:13:15",  "2022-07-26 09:13:20", "2022-07-26 09:13:25", "2022-07-26 09:13:30",  "2022-07-26 09:13:35", "2022-07-26 09:13:40", "2022-07-26 09:13:45",  "2022-07-26 09:13:50", "2022-07-26 09:13:55", "2022-07-26 09:14:00",  "2022-07-26 09:14:05", "2022-07-26 09:14:10", "2022-07-26 09:14:15",  "2022-07-26 09:14:20", "2022-07-26 09:14:25", "2022-07-26 09:14:30",  "2022-07-26 09:14:35", "2022-07-26 09:14:40", "2022-07-26 09:20:55",  "2022-07-26 09:21:00", "2022-07-26 09:21:05", "2022-07-26 09:21:10",  "2022-07-26 09:21:15", "2022-07-26 09:21:20", "2022-07-26 09:21:25",  "2022-07-26 09:21:30", "2022-07-26 09:21:35", "2022-07-26 09:21:40",  "2022-07-26 09:21:45", "2022-07-26 09:21:50", "2022-07-26 09:21:55",  "2022-07-26 09:22:00", "2022-07-26 09:22:05", "2022-07-26 09:22:10",  "2022-07-26 09:22:15", "2022-07-26 09:22:20", "2022-07-26 09:22:25",  "2022-07-26 09:22:30", "2022-07-26 09:22:35", "2022-07-26 09:22:40",  "2022-07-26 09:22:45", "2022-07-26 09:22:50", "2022-07-26 09:22:55",  "2022-07-26 09:23:00", "2022-07-26 09:23:05", "2022-07-26 09:23:10",  "2022-07-26 09:23:15", "2022-07-26 09:23:20", "2022-07-26 09:23:25",  "2022-07-26 09:23:30", "2022-07-26 09:28:10", "2022-07-26 09:28:15",  "2022-07-26 09:28:20", "2022-07-26 09:28:25", "2022-07-26 09:28:30",  "2022-07-26 09:28:35", "2022-07-26 09:28:40", "2022-07-26 09:28:45",  "2022-07-26 09:28:50", "2022-07-26 09:28:55", "2022-07-26 09:29:00",  "2022-07-26 09:29:05", "2022-07-26 09:29:10", "2022-07-26 09:29:15",  "2022-07-26 09:29:20", "2022-07-26 09:29:25", "2022-07-26 09:29:30",  "2022-07-26 09:29:35", "2022-07-26 09:29:40", "2022-07-26 09:29:45",  "2022-07-26 09:29:50", "2022-07-26 09:29:55", "2022-07-26 09:30:00",  "2022-07-26 09:30:05", "2022-07-26 09:30:10", "2022-07-26 09:30:15",  "2022-07-26 09:30:20", "2022-07-26 09:30:25", "2022-07-26 09:30:30",  "2022-07-26 09:30:35", "2022-07-26 09:30:40"), ch4_ppm = c(27.75, 
36.32, 51.63, 54.56, 92, 121.5, 127.6, 193.7, 189.3, 279.2, 323.2, 
368.6, 426.1, 485.7, 545.7, 492.8, 548.1, 751.6, 820, 892, 959,  1018, 1080, 1152, 1214, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  NA, NA,
3.346, 3.672, 3.958, 8.33, 21.09, 47.68, 53.71, 150.8, 
190.6, 222.4, 267.3, 326.4, 314.5, 375.8, 435.3, 595.7, 534.3, 
740.6, 819, 873, 923, 987, 1067, 1140, 1206, NA, NA, NA, NA,  NA, NA, NA, 14.71, 14.7, 29.95, 48.91, 75.21, 102, 129.9, 131.9, 
199.3, 140, 272.2, 313.3, 354.1, 398.4, 449.3, 503.6, 557.9, 
614.2, 676, 734.4, 628.6, 672.4, 536.2, 767, 1002, 1054, 1099,  1143, 1194, NA, NA), co2_ppm = c(491, 500.3, 509.1, 517.7, 526.6, 
530.3, 534.7, 536.1, 539, 542.5, 549.8, 557.7, 570.5, 584.4, 
602.6, 622.9, 648.3, 674.4, 705.5, 736.2, 772.3, 807, 846, 883,  927, 967, 1010, 1049, 1094, 1135, 1181, 1226, 1268, 1313, 1359,  1403, 1445, 426.7, 427.2, 427, 428.5, 428.5, 429.8, 430.5, 434.4, 
438.4, 444.4, 452.9, 464.3, 477.2, 493.1, 510.4, 532.7, 556, 
584.6, 613.6, 648.9, 681.6, 719, 753.5, 794.5, 831, 874, 917,  958, 1001, 1045, 1090, 1131, 439.7, 436.8, 436, 435.3, 436.9, 
438.7, 443.4, 450.5, 457.3, 467.6, 480.3, 495.3, 512.9, 532.9, 
554.9, 578.3, 605.7, 633.1, 664.3, 692.8, 727.2, 758.5, 794.7,  828, 868, 903, 945, 983, 1023, 1062, 1104), chamber_temp_degC = c(20.85, 
20.86, 20.87, 20.88, 20.89, 20.9, 20.91, 20.91, 20.93, 20.94, 
20.96, 20.96, 20.97, 20.98, 20.99, 20.99, 21, 21.01, 21.02, 21.03, 
21.03, 21.05, 21.06, 21.06, 21.07, 21.08, 21.09, 21.09, 21.09, 
21.1, 21.11, 21.11, 21.12, 21.13, 21.13, 21.14, 21.15, 21.6, 
21.6, 21.61, 21.61, 21.62, 21.63, 21.63, 21.64, 21.65, 21.67, 
21.67, 21.67, 21.67, 21.68, 21.68, 21.69, 21.69, 21.7, 21.71, 
21.71, 21.72, 21.72, 21.73, 21.73, 21.74, 21.74, 21.75, 21.75, 
21.76, 21.76, 21.76, 21.77, 22.1, 22.12, 22.13, 22.14, 22.15, 
22.16, 22.17, 22.18, 22.19, 22.19, 22.2, 22.2, 22.21, 22.21, 
22.22, 22.22, 22.23, 22.23, 22.24, 22.24, 22.25, 22.26, 22.26, 
22.26, 22.27, 22.27, 22.27, 22.27, 22.27, 22.27, 22.27), measurement_id = c(1,  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,  2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,  2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,  3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)), row.names = c(21L,  22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L,  35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L,  48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 132L, 133L,  134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L,  145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L,  156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 219L, 220L, 221L,  222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 232L,  233L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 241L, 242L, 243L,  244L, 245L, 246L, 247L, 248L, 249L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want the output to be a data frame of the calculated slope next to the start time of each sequence (the timestamp in the first row of each ID) next to the calculated slope from the regression like below

```
time          slope    measurement_id
2022-09-18    8.67     1
2022-09-18    5.34     2
...           ...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What are your dependent and independent variables?

Comment: Time is my independent variable and ch4_ppm is my dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `group_by` "measurement_id" and add a column with is the row id per group using `row_number` and `summarise` the slope which is in the `coefficients` of `lm` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(measurement_id) %>% 
  mutate(rowid = row_number()) %>% 
  summarise(time = first(time), 
            slope = lm(ch4_ppm ~ rowid)$coefficients['rowid'])
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   measurement_id time                slope
#>            <dbl> <chr>               <dbl>
#> 1              1 2022-07-26 09:11:40  51.8
#> 2              2 2022-07-26 09:20:55  53.7
#> 3              3 2022-07-26 09:28:10  42.3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution avoiding tidyverse and dealing with the formatting of the time, assuming you are interested in time as a continuous variable measured in seconds. Although, it isn't clear from the question what units you want to measure time in. Saving your data as a data frame called `df`.

```
df$time <- lubridate::ymd_hms(df$time)

# function to subset data, calculate time difference in seconds,
# and get linear regression slope
getSlope <- function(id){
  data <- df[df$measurement_id==id,]
  data$t <- data$time - min(data$time)
  fit <- lm(ch4_ppm ~ t, data=data)
  return(fit$coefficients['t'])
}

# new data frame to hold results
results <- data.frame(id = 1:3, slope=NA)  
results$slope <- sapply(1:3,getSlope)
results

#>  id     slope
#>1  1 10.365175
#>2  2 10.735887
#>3  3  8.465798
```